"unmatched host" error when connecting to NFS share
I am getting an "unmatched host" error after configuring an NFS share using a hostname. Whitelisting using IP address works fine.

On a server called "server1", I have this line in the /etc/exports listing both values server2 and it's FQDN, server2.tailcb999.ts.net:
/volume1/my-files server2(rw,async,no_wdelay,no_root_squash,insecure_locks,sec=sys,anonuid=1025,anongid=100) server2.tailcb213.ts.net(rw,async,no_wdelay,no_root_squash,insecure_locks,sec=sys,anonuid=1025,anongid=100)

On a server called "server2", I run this command:
mount -t nfs server1:/volume1/my-files /tmp/mount-sample/

After running the above command, I get this error:
mount.nfs: access denied by server while mounting server1:/volume1/my-files

After checking server logs, I see this:
2024-05-28T00:59:48+03:00 server1 mountd[10698]: refused mount request from 101.127.119.103 for /volume1/my-files (/volume1/my-files): unmatched host

101.127.119.103 is the IP address of "server2".
How come NFS refuses to accept connections from a host that is clearly allowed?
P.S. in an attempt to understand more about this problem, I ran nslookup:
$ nslookup server2
Server:         100.100.100.100
Address:        100.100.100.100#53

Name:   server2.tailcb999.ts.net
Address: 101.127.119.103
$

$ nslookup server2.tailcb999.ts.net
Server:         100.100.100.100
Address:        100.100.100.100#53

Name:   server2.tailcb999.ts.net
Address: 101.127.119.103
$

$ nslookup 101.127.119.103
Server:         100.100.100.100
Address:        100.100.100.100#53

101.127.119.103.in-addr.arpa    name = server2.tailcb999.ts.net.
$

I am using Tailscale to connect server1 and server2. server1 is a Synology DS218+ box, while server2 is a regular linux box. Whitelisting another box, let's call it server3 that is in the same LAN like this works too (note the .lan zone):
/volume1/my-files server3.lan(rw,async,no_wdelay,no_root_squash,insecure_locks,sec=sys,anonuid=1025,anongid=100)


You#re showing an A record, but do you have a PTR record?
Or, does it work if you use the FQDN rather than short name in /etc/exports?

It does not work using FQDN name either, just tried it out of curiosity. I'm not quite an expert in DNS vocabulary and concepts... what's a PTR record and why it may be important here? I'm willing to try adding it & see what happens

I've added a couple more nslookup outputs

This should be a comment, not an answer.
